# XSLT, finding out if last child node is a specific element

Tags: xslt, xpath

Look at the following two examples:

```
<foo>some text <bar/> and maybe some more</foo>
```

and

```
<foo>some text <bar/> and a last <bar/></foo>
```

Mixed text nodes and `bar` elements within the `foo` element. Now I am in `foo`, and want to find out if the last child is a `bar`. The first example should prove false, as there are text after the `bar`, but the second example should be true.

How can I accomplish this with XSLT?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short solution and a writing style suggestion. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just select the last node of the `<foo>` element and then use `self` axis to resolve the node type.

```
/foo/node()[position()=last()]/self::bar
```

This XPath expression returns an empty set (which equates to boolean false) if the last node is not an element. If you want to specifically get value `true` or `false`, wrap this expression in the XPath function `boolean()`. Use `self::*` instead of `self::bar` to match any element as the last node.

Input XML document:

```
<root>
    <foo>some text <bar/> and maybe some more</foo>
    <foo>some text <bar/> and a last <bar/></foo>
</root>
```

XSLT document example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="node()[position()=last()]/self::bar">
            <xsl:text>bar element at the end&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>text at the end&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output of the stylesheet:

```
text at the end
bar element at the end
```

Comment: You can also simplify the predicate `/foo/node()[last()]/self::bar`

Comment: jasso: +1 Good answer. I also think that `[last()]` predicate is better

Answer (score 7):

> Now I am in `foo`, and want to find
>   out if the last child is a `bar`

**Use**:

```
node()[last()][self::bar]
```

The boolean value of any non-empty node-set is `true()` and it is `false()` for otherwise. You can use the above expression directly (unmodified) as the value of the `test` attribute of any `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:when>`.

**Better, use**:

```
foo/node()[last()][self::bar]
```

as the `match` attribute of an `<xsl:template>` -- thus you write in pure "push" style.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** *This answer addresses the requirement stated in the original question title, "finding out if last child node is a text node." But the question body suggests a different requirement, and it seems that the latter requirement was the one intended by the OP.*

The previous two answers explicitly test whether the last child is a `bar` element, rather than directly testing whether it is a text node. This is correct if foo contains *only* "mixed text nodes and bar elements" **and** never has zero children.

But you may want to test directly whether the last child is a text node:

1. For readability of stylesheet logic
2. In case the element contains other children besides elements and text: e.g. comments or processing instructions
3. In case the element has no children

Maybe you know the latter two will never occur in your case (but from your question I would guess that #3 could). Or maybe you think so but aren't sure, or maybe you hadn't thought about it. In either case, it's safer to test directly for what you actually want to know:

```
     test="node()[last()]/self::text()"
```

Thus, building on @Dimitre's example code and input, the following XML input:

```
<root>
   <foo>some text <bar/> and maybe some more</foo>
   <foo>some text <bar/> and a pi: <?foopi param=yes?></foo>
   <foo>some text <bar/> and a comment: <!-- baz --></foo>
   <foo>some text and an element: <bar /></foo>
   <foo noChildren="true" />
</root>
```

With this XSLT template:

```
   <xsl:template match="foo">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="node()[last()]/self::text()">
            <xsl:text>text at the end;&#10;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="node()[last()]/self::*">
            <xsl:text>element at the end;&#10;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>neither text nor element child at the end;&#10;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
```

yields:

```
   text at the end;
   neither text nor element child at the end;
   neither text nor element child at the end;
   element at the end;
   neither text nor element child at the end;
```

Comment: Good addition. But preceding answers didn't change OP requeriments as it seems suggested by your first sentence. From question: `want to find out if the last child is a bar`.

Comment: @Alejandro: good point. I didn't notice that the OP himself changed the requirements, between the title and the sentence you quoted. I was going by the title.