# Moving last space from mixed-content node to outside node

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a large number of HTML files created by MS Word. I am trying to manipulate the contents of these files to extract data and whatnot.

An HTML paragraph has mixed content, and I find that often the space after an italicized or bold word is also italicized. When I `normalize-space()` this later the space is stripped and words get concatenated that should not be concatenated.

```
<p>Some text here and some <i>italicized </i>text here.</p>
```

Later transformation causes this to become

```
<p>Some text here and some <i>italicized</i>text here.</p>
```

(I am somewhat simplifying things.)

I want to end up with

```
<p>Some text here and some <i>italicized</i> text here.</p>
```

I want to identify cases where the last node inside the  element is a text node ending with whitespace, strip trailing whitespace, and add a space after the  element.

I think I can cobble together something but the XQuery is getting hairy and I have to think there is an easier way. (There might not be, but I'd be silly if I didn't ask....)

[XSLT, finding out if last child node is a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851804/xslt-finding-out-if-last-child-node-is-a-text-node) looks close, but not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Match the elements who's last child node is a text() node 
      that ends with a space. -->
  <xsl:template match="*[node()[last()]
                               [self::text()[substring(.,string-length())=' ']]]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <!--add the extra space following the matched element-->
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Match the text() node that is the last child node of an element 
      and ends with a space -->
  <xsl:template match="*/node()[last()]
                               [self::text()[substring(., string-length())=' ']]">
      <!--remove the trailing space-->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 0, string-length())"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```